# I want to get alert when any change happen in database server ? like fireabse notification but in pos[point of sale] not support google play services

Tags: android, kotlin, firebase-realtime-database

we have two different Android applications. 1st is for the customer to place the order for food. 2nd one is I want an alert in the owner app if a customer placed a food order like.. "you receive a food order". how can I receive an alert? without using the Firebase notification service.

Comment: you can use sockets for it so the owner app will listen for messages from this socket and the customer app will send messages to that socket actually firebase push notifications use this approach under the hood, but you will force to use some backend middleware to redirect the messages from customer to owner to overcome NAT problem.. the second way is (but it's a really really bad practice)  create a cloud based database and customer will write messages there and owner app will check for updates in that database e.g. every minute.. but I recommend you just to use Firebase notification service

Comment: You should learn first Firebase Cloud Message : https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/android/client

Comment: @HalilOzel actually the application is for POS so POS machine not support FCM("E/FirebaseInstanceId: Google Play services missing or without correct permission.") it gives the error . so i want to find another option ...

Comment: @easy_breezy thank you, but can you suggest me for that real time firebase database is a good option to get alert or not..??

Comment: @NikitaJain I think it's one of the best options

Comment: @easy_breezy Yes this one is working for me. but the problem is rules are defined in a real-time database system. rules set FALSE then it not working. if set it TRUE its working .. so the security issue are there..

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: @RyanM real-time Firebase database